# cv upgrade:db causes error

Tags: upgrade, cv

When I try to upgrade via cv, I get the following error:

```
In DrupalBase.php line 282:

[Error] Call to undefined function _drupal_flush_css_js()
```

I am able to do the upgrade within the GUI.

Any thoughts?

Verbose listing:

```
~/p$ cv -vvv upgrade:db

Box Requirements Checker
========================

> Using PHP 8.1.13
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /usr/local/php81/lib/php.ini

> Checking Box requirements:
  ✔ The application requires a version matching ">=7.3.0".
  ✔ The application requires the extension "json".
  ✔ The package "psy/psysh" requires the extension "json".
  ✔ The package "jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter" requires the extension "tokenizer".
  ✔ The package "nikic/php-parser" requires the extension "tokenizer".
  ✔ The package "psy/psysh" requires the extension "tokenizer".


 [OK] Your system is ready to run the application.


[BootTrait] Start
[BootTrait] Attempting to set verbose error reporting
[BootTrait] Call standard cv bootstrap
[Bootstrap] Options: {
    "dynamicSettingsFile": "phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/settings_location.php",
    "env": "CIVICRM_SETTINGS",
    "prefetch": true,
    "settingsFile": null,
    "search": true,
    "cmsType": null,
    "httpHost": "",
    "output": {}
}
[Bootstrap] Find settings file
[Bootstrap] Load supplemental configuration for "/home/myuser/p/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php"
[Bootstrap] Find CMS root for "/home/myuser/p"
[Bootstrap] Found "drupal" in "/home/myuser/p"
[Bootstrap] Simulate web environment in CLI
[Bootstrap] Load settings file "/home/myuser/p/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php"
[Bootstrap] Initialize class loader
[Bootstrap] Call core bootstrap

In DrupalBase.php line 282:

  [Error]
  Call to undefined function _drupal_flush_css_js()


Exception trace:
  at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/DrupalBase.php:282
 CRM_Utils_System_DrupalBase->clearResourceCache() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php:362
 CRM_Core_Resources->resetCacheCode() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php:138
 CRM_Core_Resources->__construct() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php:557
 Civi\Core\Container::createResources() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php:1130
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php:618
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php:558
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi.php:175
 Civi::service() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php:116
 CRM_Core_Resources::singleton() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/nz.co.fuzion.environmentindicator/environmentindicator.php:13
 environmentindicator_civicrm_config() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:271
 CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/DrupalBase.php:73
 CRM_Utils_Hook_DrupalBase->invokeViaUF() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:306
 Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:251
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73
 Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:260
 Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:167
 CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php:1382
 CRM_Utils_Hook::config() at /home/myuser/domains/mydomain/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php:94
 CRM_Core_Config::singleton() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/src/Bootstrap.php:104
 Civi\Cv\Bootstrap->boot() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/src/Util/BootTrait.php:69
 Civi\Cv\Command\UpgradeDbCommand->_boot_full() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/src/Util/BootTrait.php:44
 Civi\Cv\Command\UpgradeDbCommand->boot() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/src/Command/UpgradeDbCommand.php:31
 Civi\Cv\Command\UpgradeDbCommand->execute() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:127
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:637
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:190
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/src/Application.php:66
 Civi\Cv\Application->doRun() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:101
 Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/src/Application.php:32
 Civi\Cv\Application::main() at phar:///home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv/bin/cv:28
 require() at /home/myuser/vendor/bin/cv:14

upgrade:db [--out OUT] [--flat [FLAT]] [--dry-run] [--retry] [--skip] [--step] [--level LEVEL] [--hostname HOSTNAME] [-t|--test] [-U|--user USER]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds drupal hasn't had a chance to boot yet before that gets called. Try disabling the environmentindicator extension first, since it's calling it during hook_config which might be too early here.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Thanks!